# Can't use override in function c++

Tags: c++, function, audio, juce

So i've been trying to process audio using JUCE and followed a tutorial and there he used override on one of the functions but when i do it it says "Expected function body after function declarator". The goal is to play random white noise as explained by the video.

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjNeYI6-uNE&index=11&list=PLLgJJsrdwhPxa6-02-CeHW8ocwSwl2jnu

Code:

```
/*
  ==============================================================================

    This file was auto-generated!

  ==============================================================================
*/

#include "MainComponent.h"

//==============================================================================
MainComponent::MainComponent()
{
    // Make sure you set the size of the component after
    // you add any child components.
    setSize (800, 600);

    // specify the number of input and output channels that we want to open
    setAudioChannels (2, 2);
}

MainComponent::~MainComponent()
{
    // This shuts down the audio device and clears the audio source.
    shutdownAudio();
}

//==============================================================================
void MainComponent::prepareToPlay (int samplesPerBlockExpected, double sampleRate)
{
    // This function will be called when the audio device is started, or when
    // its settings (i.e. sample rate, block size, etc) are changed.

    // You can use this function to initialise any resources you might need,
    // but be careful - it will be called on the audio thread, not the GUI thread.

    // For more details, see the help for AudioProcessor::prepareToPlay()
}

void MainComponent::getNextAudioBlock (const AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill) override /*this one gets the error*/
{
    for (int channel = 0; channel < bufferToFill.buffer->getNumChannels(); ++channel)
    {
        float* const buffer = bufferToFill.buffer->getWritePointer(channel, bufferToFill.startSample);

        for (int sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.numSamples; ++sample)
        {
            buffer[sample] = (random.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f) * 0.25;
        }
    }

    bufferToFill.clearActiveBufferRegion();
}

void MainComponent::releaseResources()
{
    // This will be called when the audio device stops, or when it is being
    // restarted due to a setting change.

    // For more details, see the help for AudioProcessor::releaseResources()
}

//==============================================================================
void MainComponent::paint (Graphics& g)
{
    // (Our component is opaque, so we must completely fill the background with a solid colour)
    g.fillAll (getLookAndFeel().findColour (ResizableWindow::backgroundColourId));

    // You can add your drawing code here!
}

void MainComponent::resized()
{
    // This is called when the MainContentComponent is resized.
    // If you add any child components, this is where you should
    // update their positions.
}
```

.h file:

```
    /*
  ==============================================================================

    This file was auto-generated!

  ==============================================================================
*/

#pragma once

#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"

//==============================================================================
/*
    This component lives inside our window, and this is where you should put all
    your controls and content.
*/
class MainComponent   : public AudioAppComponent
{
public:
    //==============================================================================
    MainComponent();
    ~MainComponent();

    //==============================================================================
    void prepareToPlay (int samplesPerBlockExpected, double sampleRate) override;
    void getNextAudioBlock (const AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill) override;
    void releaseResources() override;

    //==============================================================================
    void paint (Graphics& g) override;
    void resized() override;

private:
    //==============================================================================
    // Your private member variables go here...

    Random random;
    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (MainComponent)
};
```

Main.cpp

```
/*
  ==============================================================================

    This file was auto-generated!

    It contains the basic startup code for a JUCE application.

  ==============================================================================
*/

#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"
#include "MainComponent.h"

//==============================================================================
class AudioOutApplication  : public JUCEApplication
{
public:
    //==============================================================================
    AudioOutApplication() {}

    const String getApplicationName() override       { return ProjectInfo::projectName; }
    const String getApplicationVersion() override    { return ProjectInfo::versionString; }
    bool moreThanOneInstanceAllowed() override       { return true; }

    //==============================================================================
    void initialise (const String& commandLine) override
    {
        // This method is where you should put your application's initialisation code..

        mainWindow.reset (new MainWindow (getApplicationName()));
    }

    void shutdown() override
    {
        // Add your application's shutdown code here..

        mainWindow = nullptr; // (deletes our window)
    }

    //==============================================================================
    void systemRequestedQuit() override
    {
        // This is called when the app is being asked to quit: you can ignore this
        // request and let the app carry on running, or call quit() to allow the app to close.
        quit();
    }

    void anotherInstanceStarted (const String& commandLine) override
    {
        // When another instance of the app is launched while this one is running,
        // this method is invoked, and the commandLine parameter tells you what
        // the other instance's command-line arguments were.
    }

    //==============================================================================
    /*
        This class implements the desktop window that contains an instance of
        our MainComponent class.
    */
    class MainWindow    : public DocumentWindow
    {
    public:
        MainWindow (String name)  : DocumentWindow (name,
                                                    Desktop::getInstance().getDefaultLookAndFeel()
                                                                          .findColour (ResizableWindow::backgroundColourId),
                                                    DocumentWindow::allButtons)
        {
            setUsingNativeTitleBar (true);
            setContentOwned (new MainComponent(), true);

           #if JUCE_IOS || JUCE_ANDROID
            setFullScreen (true);
           #else
            setResizable (true, true);
            centreWithSize (getWidth(), getHeight());
           #endif

            setVisible (true);
        }

        void closeButtonPressed() override
        {
            // This is called when the user tries to close this window. Here, we'll just
            // ask the app to quit when this happens, but you can change this to do
            // whatever you need.
            JUCEApplication::getInstance()->systemRequestedQuit();
        }

        /* Note: Be careful if you override any DocumentWindow methods - the base
           class uses a lot of them, so by overriding you might break its functionality.
           It's best to do all your work in your content component instead, but if
           you really have to override any DocumentWindow methods, make sure your
           subclass also calls the superclass's method.
        */

    private:
        JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (MainWindow)
    };

private:
    std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> mainWindow;
};

//==============================================================================
// This macro generates the main() routine that launches the app.
START_JUCE_APPLICATION (AudioOutApplication)
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Are you compiling in C++11 mode (or higher) ? else `override` will indeed produce error.

Comment: Are those member functions defined as `virtual` in the base class?

Comment: pretty sure im compiling in c++11 yes

Comment: yea its virtual it seems

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the `override` from the function definition in the `.cpp` file. This specifier can only appear in a member function declaration (i.e., in the header file), unless you're defining the function inside the header file, in which case it can appear just before the function body.